# Intellij Run Target with maven

Tags: java, docker, maven, intellij-idea, minikube

I'm trying to run a simple buildjob (mvn clean install) inside a container instead of running it locally in my Intellij IDEA. But I must be missing something. I get a container started and maven starts building, but then immediate fails since no code is in the /tmp//-folder

I have a Run/Debug configuration that points to a Minikube "run target". From the target I pull an the image (successfully) and set the location of maven and java and a project path on target (/app). But when the container attempt to run mvn clean install it do so from a /tmp-folder and no code is found.

Any suggestions what might be the problem?

Comment: Looks like you have a Java maven Application and all you want to do is build it and run it.  What does it have to do with intellij?

Comment: @Tintin I try to configure it through Intellij. Intellij provides tools that allows me ask it to pull an image and then run a task on a container based of that image. So the question is mostly about Intellij and the functionality it provides and what is possible with those tools.

Comment: Look like a bug. Please, report to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue

Answer (score 1):

I guess its container problem
did you check mount point(volumn)?
can you please write your container.yml file?

Comment: I'm not aware of how Intellij provides the yml-file. I'm basically following a guide adapted for my need. The curse of convince by magic behind a nice UI, you don't get to know what happens in the background (as far as I know right now atleast)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow a ticket with this issue  in [YouTrack system](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues)